# Sending Emails With GitLab not working correctly

Tags: email, gitlab, postfix-mta

I'm trying to troubleshoot why GitLab Omnibus is not sending automated emails using Postfix, which is already installed and configured correctly (it's being used by other applications installed on the server as well).

When I make a change to an issue, while tailing the Gitlab logs, this is what I'm noticing:

> ==> /var/log/gitlab/sidekiq/current <==
>   2015-04-03_20:06:30.79386 2015-04-03T20:06:30.793Z 8126 TID-aq3vk Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer JID-460531f571f6756908805d66 INFO: start
>   2015-04-03_20:06:31.53363 sendmail: recipients with -t option not supported
>
> ==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
>
> Sent mail to user@company.com (48.3ms)
>
> ==> /var/log/gitlab/sidekiq/current <==
>   2015-04-03_20:06:31.57039 2015-04-03T20:06:31.570Z 8126 TID-aq3vk Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer JID-460531f571f6756908805d66 INFO: done: 0.776 sec

I sanitized the email address, but it is sending to a correct address.

I'm guessing the issue is related to the " sendmail: recipients with -t option not supported"

However, I cannot find anybody else out there who has had this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: The error message means `sendmail` is being invoked with incorrect options.  You are not showing us that code so we can't tell you how to fix it.

Comment: Right, however, I cannot find any way to change the syntax that GitLab uses when it executes sendmail. As such, I am at a loss at how to fix this issue.

Comment: I have asked another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35367848/configure-and-test-gitlab-comunity-email-setting, but it's without answer and down voted for reason I don't understand

Answer (score 11):

I fixed this issue by switching GitLab to SMTP by following the guide here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/smtp.md

It seems like SMTP is documented in greater detail.

Comment: I'm trying to fix this issue for gitlab 8, emails are not sent at all. No entries regarding mail are in any log and I tried posix and smtp (exact example for gmail), which version are you using ?

Comment: @PavelNiedoba, did you get this figured out?